# Pass array/hash to model attribute from form parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, form-for

I have a model with an accessible attribute `:days` in a Rails3 app.

In my form I have a series of checkboxes which represent each day.

I'd like to pass an array of all the selected 'days' into my model for processing in a `before_save` callback.

My question is, can I construct a parameters hash without ajax/js using either standard form helpers, or if not, by defining the parameters hash for each checkbox?

The following is just a guess on how I might implement this as I'm not quite sure how rails processes the parameters in `name` attribute:

Something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="my_model[days][0]" id="my_model_days">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="my_model[days][1]" id="my_model_days">

...?
```

and if so will it pass an array to my model?

Any suggestions on good tutorials or threads on how to construct these parameter structures within Rails forms are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fields_for
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: Cool, I've only used fields_for to pass model attributes with accepts_nested_att... before, didn't know you could use it like that, cheers!